# Implementing Runnable in Enum

Tags: java, enums, runnable

I am just playing around with enum and I wanted to see how it behaves under some crazy scenarios. Well, few java nerds might know that we can actually implement a interface in Enums. 
So I came up with below code and wanted to know if the thread is created and called. I am curious if anyone can explain why the sysout is not printed. The below code is valid i.e compiles fine and executes. It just prints nothing. Can anyone explain clearly?

Also why values() method is not declared either in Enum class or Object class. Why the values method is provided by java compiler. Why the Sun/Oracle din't think of implementing it in Enum class.

```
 package com.test;


  enum MyEnum implements Runnable{

      ENUM1,ENUM2,ENUM3;
      public void run() {

          System.out.println("Inside MyEnum"+Thread.currentThread().getName());
      }
}


public class EnumTesting {

    MyEnum en;

      public static void main(String[] args) {

    EnumTesting test = new EnumTesting();

          Thread t = new Thread(test.en);
        t.start();

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sweeper...  After initializing it , the sysout is printed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It just prints nothing. Can anyone explain clearly?

Note that you did not give `en` a value. Therefore, it is `null`. When `null` is passed to the constructor of `Thread`, the thread is [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread-java.lang.Runnable-) to do nothing:

> **Parameters:**
>
> `target` - the object whose run method is invoked when this thread is started. If null, this classes `run` method does nothing.

You can do this instead:

```
new Thread(MyEnum.ENUM1).start();
```

> Why the Sun/Oracle din't think of implementing it in Enum class.

My speculation is that `values`, if it were in `Enum<T>`, should be `abstract`, but static methods can't be abstract.

Answer (score 1):

1)  Because `test.en` is null, you never initialize it.

2) Implementing values() must be done by the compiler because the array type is the type of the concrete Enum, here `MyEnum[]`. If it would be declared in Enum class, it would need to have a return type of `Enum[]`.

Comment: Thanks Dorian..  What is the issue of  having return type of Enum[]... Just curious

Comment: because you want it to have return type of `MyEnum[]`.

Comment: @Stunner When you do `MyEnum.values()`, you'd get a `MyEnum[]`, not a `Enum[]`, right? Returning a `Enum[]` would be less helpful as you will need to cast.

Comment: But nowadays, `Enum` is generic, so it _can_ be written to return a `T[]`. See my answer for possibly why they still haven't done this.

Comment: Yes. They could have came up with something like T[] .  The abstarct and static method point makes sense.. Thanks.... Thank you both.   Let's see if somebody has any other point...

Comment: Since stackoverflow doesn't allow to have 2 accepted answers..  I had to choose only one..

Comment: Apart from that: Why should they declare it in the Enum class? What would be the benetit of calling Enum.values() directly, and what would you expect that to return?